# How dose Keras train a model with out one column (feature)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I prepare to train a model with the dataframe like this:

```
   _id   c1   c2  target
0  abc1   1   2   True
1  abc2   1   1   True
2  abc3   0   1   True
3  abc4   1   3   True
```

and because _id is a string (Object), so it cannot be used in the training of neural network. So, I hope the model can ignore it but do not drop it. Because after I get the prediction, I hope I can return find the id of it.

Comment: You can simply store your `_id` column somewhere else and use it later.

Comment: @YilunZhang How can I know which row for which _id? Because later, I will order the target with the possibility. And get the top 10. I need the top 10's id.

Comment: @YilunZhang Ok, I get an idea, I will re-add the id into the result and do the sort. Thx

Comment: That is correct.